# сформировать шестнадцатеричный дамп заданного пользователем бинарного файла c++

Tags: c++

Можете мне объяснить смысл задачи на С++
Вот сама задача

в) сформировать шестнадцатеричный дамп заданного пользователем бинарного файла, образовав его таким образом, чтобы вместо каждого байта входного файла было выведено значение в шестнадцатеричной системе. Сформированный дамп вывести в другой файл. Для работы с файлами использовать функции библиотеки cstdio.

Буду рад вашей помощи.

Comment: [`hexdump`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

Вас просят для каждого байта во входном файле вывести его шестнадцатеричное представление (т.е. две шестнадцатеричные цифры) в выходной файл.